# Why is 就 used in ...我实际上在立法会内曾就胶袋问题提出质询...?

Tags: word-choice

兩個月前，我其實在立法會內曾就膠袋問題提出質詢，因為我們有一次 到沙灘和路邊的郊野公園去，看見那情況感到很恐怖。 I looked it on MDBG but didn't get anything of important meaning.

Answer (score 3):

**ABC** calls this a 介词 (converb) and defines it like this:

> with regard to; concerning

Here's the examples they use:

> 就A 来说
>
> Jiù A lái shuō
>
> with regard to A

And:

> 就A 而言
>
> Jiù A ér yán
>
> with regard to A

就膠袋問題提出質詢 = as for the inquires raised in regard to the problems with the pastic bags